# Exporting large file from BigQuery to Google cloud using wildcard

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, export

I have 8Gb table in BigQuery that I'm trying to export to Google Cloud Storage (GCS). If I specify url as it is, I'm getting an error

```
Errors:
Table gs://***.large_file.json too large to be exported to a single file. Specify a uri including a * to shard export. See 'Exporting data into one or more files' in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data. (error code: invalid)
```

Okay... I'm specifying * in a file name, but it exports it in 2 files: one 7.13Gb and one ~150Mb.

**UPD**. I thought I should get about 8 files, 1Gb each? Am I wrong? Or what am I doing wrong?

P.S. I tried this in WebUI mode as well as using Java library.

Comment: Whats the question? When you specify * in GCS path you get multiple files. That's the feature. You can obtain and further join the file if you need in 1 single piece.

Comment: You've got your table exported to GCS as two files  - so why you think you are doing something wrong?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Shouldn't I get 8 files, 1Gb each?

Comment: @Pentium10 I guess I should get about 8 files, 1Gb each.

Comment: I've filled in a bug report to update the documentation with the relevant information. Something is off here, maybe the internal compression size is at 1GB but when exported flat results 7GB, but this should be confirmed officially https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111569287

Comment: @Pentium10 To be honest, I'm a bit upset about this.. It'd be very nice feature to be able to have small separated files instead of one large.

Comment: please post this as a feature request, it can go to the same ticket

Comment: @Samuel Liew you delete an answer without knowing what you do. The other question can be marked as duplicate since it doesn't have accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

To export it to GCP you have to go to the table and click EXPORT > Export to GCS.

[image: BigQuery export table]

This opens the following screen

[image: Export to GCS]

In **Select GCS location** you define the bucket, the folder and the file.

For instances, you have a bucket named *daria_bucket* (*Use only lowercase letters, numbers, hyphens (-), and underscores (_). Dots (.) may be used to form a valid domain name.*) and want to save the file(s) in the root of the bucket with the name *test*, then you write (in Select GCS location)

```
daria_bucket/test.csv
```

Because the file is too big, you're getting an error. To fix it, you'll have to break it down into more files using wildcard. So, you'll need to add *, just like that

```
daria_bucket/test*.csv
```

[image: Wildcard export to GCS]

This is going to store, inside of the bucket daria_bucket, all the data extracted from the table in more than one file named test000000000000, test000000000001, test000000000002, ... testX.

In my case (more than 1 year after you've asked the question), using a random table of 1,25 GBs, got 16 files with 80,3 MBs each.

Answer (score 3):

For files of certain size or larger, BigQuery will export to multiple GCS files - that's why it asks for the "*" glob.

Once you have multiple files in GCS, you can join them into 1 with the `compose` operation:

```
gsutil compose gs://bucket/obj1 [gs://bucket/obj2 ...] gs://bucket/composite
```

- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention the main issue I faced. I thought I will have multiple files, 1Gb each

Comment: If you compose the files blindly, you might have issues, e.g. CSV headers as part of your data, or invalid JSON syntax due to missing commas. So some additional parsing might be required, if you need to join the files into one.